# How to get all open URL in every tab of every Window in Safari?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, safari, applescript

I am using NSAppleScript to tell Safari to return URL of all opened tabs as follows:

```
let script = NSAppleScript.init(source: "tell application \"Safari\" to get URL of every tab of every window")
var errorInfo: NSDictionary?
let eventDescriptor:NSAppleEventDescriptor = (script?.executeAndReturnError(&errorInfo))!
print(eventDescriptor.stringValue)
```

Above returns nil. Telling to return current URL do work.

```
"tell application \"Safari\" to return URL of front document as string"
```

---

How to get all opened URL in every tab of every window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result will be an NSDescriptor representing a list of lists of strings. Either you:

1. Coerce the list to string in AppleScript before returning it, using a suitable text item delimiter upon which you can then split the string into a list of strings in Swift (cheat),
2. Use a couple of nested loops to unpack the list descriptors yourself (tedious), or
3. Ditch `NSAppleScript` and use the [AppleScript-ObjC bridge](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=175562#p175562) instead (a little fiddly to set up, but by far the simplest and most capable to use).